# Codeigniter get key of the row object

Tags: codeigniter

I am using codeigniter. I have a query done to the database which returns a object $a.

To access the value of the property of $a i have to do something like

```
$a->property
```

Is there any way I can find the name of the property as well? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help you

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM some_table');

foreach ($query->list_fields() as $field)
{
   echo $field;
}
```

Or

```
$fields = $this->db->field_data('table_name');

foreach ($fields as $field)
{
   echo $field->name;
   echo $field->type;
   echo $field->max_length;
   echo $field->primary_key;
}
```